# Rule or trigger causes unexpected overflow error

Tags: sql-server, triggers, rule, integer-overflow

I have a scenario where I need a certain trigger to fire for all rows within a table.

The simplest way to do that, as far as I know, is to execute a dumb update, being that defined as one that does not change data at all, just executes. One simple example is this one:

```
update PFUNC set CODCOLIGADA = CODCOLIGADA
```

This has been working fine until now but on a new production database we plugged that into I had a very weird error, executing the example above:

> The conversion of the varchar value '301947' overflowed an INT2 column. 
>       Use a larger integer column.

This makes no sense at all, since, if a value is stored within a cell, it should be, of course, compliant with the data type defined by that table schema.

But bear with me... to make it weirder, this table doesn't even have a row with the field CODCOLIGADA containing 301947. Executing `select CODCOLIGADA from dbo.PFUNC where CODCOLIGADA = 301947` yields no result.

If I do that using quotes, I get the same data type error as above:

```
select codcoligada from dbo.PFUNC where CODCOLIGADA = '301947'
```

returns

> The conversion of the varchar value '301947' overflowed an INT2 column. 
>       Use a larger integer column.

This is the information for this field:
[image]

This is the version information:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015 12:32:14   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

My understanding is that if that value (301947) is contained in the table, it should be truncated somehow since it violates the schema just by existing. If it's not there, it makes no sense that the update would break.

Am I missing some caveat or quirk shadowy behavior here?

**UPDATE: Detail the user-defined type**

[image: DCODCOLIGADA]

Comment: This looks like a user defined data type column. Could you post the definition of that as well?

Comment: @VKarthik, I updated the post to include that

Comment: Are you sure that  you are updating the correct table in the correct DB and schema? Many of us have made the mistake of having the wrong DB selected in SSMS

Comment: @D.Melo I agree with simon. The data type definition too doesn't help much. Could you just check if you are running against the right db and in the right server? I just did a sample check of having a table with integer data and then converting into smallint but it failed. So I am not sure how is it possible to have data still residing if your data type is now smallint.

Comment: Using a trigger instead of a query or stored procedure to process multiple rows is weird. It means that the trigger begs to be refactored into a stored procedure. If the trigger runs per row, the stored procedure will end up being orders of magnitude faster simply because it works on the entire table, not a row at a time

Comment: As for your specific problem, it's impossible to help without the schema of all relevant tables, types, rules and the trigger code. This isn't a SQL Server issue. If the problem appeared after a migration, it means that something was missed or added during the migration. Possibly, the *data* is different

Comment: For example `smallint` is a 16-bit value. It can only handle numbers  up to ±32768. Where did 301947 come from? Did the trigger try to store a 32-bit value in a 16-bit field? Post the trigger code

Answer (score 1):

Ther is a **RULE** bound to your datatype, `RCODCOLIGADA`.
The problem is in that rule.

Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```
create rule varchar_rule  
as 
@cod not in ('301947');
go 


create table dbo.test_rule (cod smallint);
go

exec sp_bindrule 'varchar_rule', 'dbo.test_rule.cod'
go


insert into dbo.test_rule
values(1);
```

> Msg 244, Level 16, State 2, Line 22 The conversion of the varchar
>   value '301947' overflowed an INT2 column. Use a larger integer column.
>   The statement has been terminated.

The rule compares the entered value that is perfect smallint to a varchar value '301947' (it can be `like`, `in`, `<>` or any other comparison).

The smallint data type has the precedence respected to varchar, so there is no conversion smallint to varchar but viceversa, varchar to smallint, so you get the error.

Maybe some days ago the base type for your user defined type was int and not smallint so the conversion never get the error